# How to initialize std::vector of std:pair of fixed length with default values?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Assuming a struct containing a std::vector with items of type std::pair.

```
struct block {
    std::vector<std::pair<key_t, value_t>> items;
    block(const Data& d) : items()
    {
        items = std::vector<std::pair<key_t, value_t>>(d.size_);
    }
};
```

Later in the code, I assign a value to the vector at position 0:

```
block<key_t, value_t> b(*this);
std::pair<key_t, value_t> item = std::pair<key_t, value_t>(k, v);
b.items[0] = item;
```

Later in the code, I want to iterate over the vector and expect `&bucket_item != NULL` to be true only at position 0, because I only assigned a value at this position. In fact, `&bucket_item != NULL` is always true.

```
for (std::pair<key_t, value_t> item : b.items)
{
    if (&item != NULL)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

I am not able to initialize the vector with NULL values like so:

```
items = std::vector<std::pair<key_t, value_t>>(d.size_, NULL);
```

How to solve this?

Comment: `NULL` is a pointer, so you would need to make the vector hold pointers to `std::pair`s and do the memory management by yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you have Java background, C++ is a bit different.

```
items = std::vector<std::pair<key_t, value_t>>(d.size_);
```

`items` has already been initialized with its default constructor. The line above creates another default initialized container and assigns it to `items`, which is unnecessary.

In:

```
b.items[0] = item;
```

You need to make sure that the vector is big enough, because it does not allocate elements for you in `operator[]`. Either do `b.items.push_front/back(item)` or insert it at a specific position using `vector::insert`, e.g. `b.items.insert(b.items.begin(), item)`. `push_xxx` and `insert` do allocate memory for new elements.

When you do

```
for (std::pair<key_t, value_t> item : b.items) 
{
    if (&item != NULL)
```

It iterates over all existing elements in the container. `item` is stored by value (unlike Java) in the container, so that it exists at a non-NULL address and cannot be possibly be equal to `NULL`.

However, expression `for(std::pair<key_t, value_t> item : b.items)` creates a copy of each element on the stack (also at non-NULL address), you probably want that to be `for(std::pair<key_t, value_t>& item : b.items)` to just refer to the element rather than copy it (note the ampersand symbol on the left of `items`). If you do not intend to modify `item` inside the loop, you may like to use `const` qualifier as well to make your intent clear to the reader of the code. e.g. `for(std::pair<key_t, value_t> const& item : b.items)`.

And because you use `C++11` anyway, you do not have to spell out the type of the container element, just use `auto`:

```
for (auto const& item : b.items) 
    // do something to item
```

Comment: Also, the statement `&item != NULL` will always be true. Not just in this example, but in any valid C++-code.

Comment: Just being nitpicky here -- if the `pair` ins't being modified in the for each loop, I would even throw in the `const` just to be explicit about the intention of the loop

Answer (score 2):

When you create an `std::vector` with a length `len` like this `std::vector<T> tVec(len)`, you are creating a `vector` with `len` default-constructed objects of type `T`. If you want to represent a null value, you will need to resort to one of the following ways:

1. Use a sentinel value of `T` to denote an invalid value.
2. Use a [(smart-)pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) to `T` and use a [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) as the natural invalid value.
3. Wrap a class around `T` which contains a `bool` marking it as invalid.

The last option is provided by [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/quick_start.html). Here's a rewrite of your code using it:

```
struct block {
    using OptionalPair_t = boost::optional<std::pair<key_t, value_t>>;
    std::vector<OptionalPair_t> items;
    block(const Data& d) : items(d.size_)
    {
    }
};
```

Since `boost::optional` is [contextually convertible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) to `bool`, you can do this:

```
for (auto& item : b.items)
{
    if (item)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your mixing here a few definitions. 
an element of `std::vector` cannot be `NULL`, because it's not a pointer. and it defenilty exists. 
`int arr[] = {1};`, can `arr[0]` be null? of course not. why would it be ? it's a real integer who seat somwhere in the memory which is not null.

if you're iterating over a std::vector elements, that means they exist, so they can not be null.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL`, or better `nullptr`, can be used to initialize a pointer value, but makes no sense to initialize, for example, an `std::string` or `std::pair<std::string, int>` with it.

If you want your vector to be empty, you can use:

```
std::vector<std::pair<key_t, value_t>> items;
```

othwerwise, if you want `n` default constructed `std::pair`s you can use:

```
std::vector<std::pair<key_t, value_t>> items(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pair are really a comination of values.  So you have to define which combination of values you consider as being the NULL equivalent for your pairs.

You can then initialize your vector with the following constructor:

```
std::vector<std::pair<key_t, value_t>> items(d.size_, make_pair(0,0)) ;
```

You just have to replace 0  with the neutral values for key_t and value_t.

*Please note that vectors really contain values, and pairs are values.  So there is no NULL pointers that would show absence of values.*

Comment: What makes you think `key_t(0)` or `value_t(0)` is a valid expression?

Comment: @Jefffrey this is an illustration, to be adatapted with the neutral value applying to key_t and value_t.  Of course, the 10 is also only an illustration for the desired size.